# Viewport meta tag problem? Style tags not working on eBay mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work out what's going on here as I believe the code below is correct. It's also correct on my Codepen Link here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZdqyLp

Whenever I put my code as HTML when creating a new eBay listing, the code works fine on eBay's desktop preview, but not on the mobile-friendly checker preview. I wonder whether in this case there's an error with the viewport meta tag.

The following below code works fine:

```
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<style>

</style>
<div id="main-body">
<p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

But the below doesn't:

```
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<style>
#test{}
</style>
<div id="main-body">
<p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

The only difference is that there's a selector inside the style tags - but why would that cause the view to break on mobiles? Surely I'm not going crazy :)

When I say it doesn't work, I mean that the mobile-friendly checker just appears blank. And you can easily see this by just starting a new eBay listing and putting the code in the HTML view.

Inline styles seem to work but then it obviously cannot be responsive. Can anyone provide some insight and a solution here? Thanks for any help.

Oh, and for some bizarre reason, this code works!

```
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<style>body{background:red}</style>
<div id="main-body">
<p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

And this doesn't style the background red but the dummy text appears rather than appearing blank:

```
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<style>
 body{background:red}
 </style>
<div id="main-body">
<p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `<meta>` should go to `<head>` tag, not `<body>`. Check Tips and Notes section: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: The third code snippet works so I think eBay might do something like stripping the head out of the code or just not require it. I'm just puzzled about how, for example, the 3rd and 4th snippets produce different results, despite the identical code